# Template parameter list with default class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Does anyone have an example for **2** and **3**? I try to understand the writing style of the standard, and other documentations about C++. In specific here the template documentation.

Both is probably wrong, but I try to understand their differences. Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

> template < parameter-list > typename(C++17) | class name(optional)    (1)
>
> template < parameter-list > typename(C++17) | class name(optional) =
>   default   (2)
>
> template < parameter-list > typename(C++17) | class ...
>   name(optional)    (3) (since C++11)
>
> 1) A template template parameter with an optional name.
>
> 2) A template template parameter with an optional name and a default.
>
> 3) A template template parameter pack with an optional name.

I am not sure if I interpret this correctly. As far as I understand...

```
// 2
template <typename T, typename Y> class Foo = default; // this can't be right, can it?

// 3
template <typename T, typename Y> class ... Foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you quote has an example for (2):

```
template<
    typename K,
    typename V,
    template<typename> typename C = my_array // C is a template template parameter
>
class Map
{
    C<K> key;
    C<V> value;
};
```

(I reformatted the code to add comment.)

Note that neither `K` nor `V` in above example is a template template parameter.

Form (3) would look like:

```
template<template<typename> typename... Args> // Args is a template template parameter pack
struct TPL {};
```

Note that *template template parameters* are a weird beast. Usually you only need *type template parameters* (as in your example) and *non-type template parameters*. The cppreference page has detailed description for them.